# Subtracting between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the below code written to subtract from different rows in SQL (but only the ones that have the same Room and Date), to get the difference in time between rows.  It works, but it misses a few needed scenarios.

I only want to subtract the most recent dates from each other.  Below, you see the beginning of my results.

```
     PatientName PatientName  OutTime   InTime  Room    Room    Value
     Patient A   Patient B     45:00.0  55:00.0 OR 1    OR 1    10
     Patient A   Patient C     45:00.0  55:00.0 OR 1    OR 1    130
     Patient B   Patient C     00:00.0  55:00.0 OR 1    OR 1    55
```

I'm trying to calculate the time the room is unused between every patient that finishes and every new patient that comes in, but in this case I'm getting every time difference between patients on the same day (ie. I do not want the difference between Patient A and Patient C)

I also would like to be able to add case statements so that if the difference is greater than a certain amount (say 90 minutes), it is not counted.

Please advise.

```
        --This code creates the table with Dummy Data

        CREATE TABLE #OperatingRoom (
        [Date] date,
        [Room] varchar(255),
    [PatientName] varchar(255),
        [InTime] time,
        [OutTime] time,
        ); 

        INSERT INTO #OperatingRoom ([Date],[Room],[PatientName],[InTime],        [OutTime])
        VALUES ('01-01-2019', 'OR 1', 'Patient A', '08:02:00','09:45:00'),
        ('01-01-2019', 'OR 1', 'Patient B', '09:55:00','11:00:00'),
        ('01-01-2019', 'OR 1', 'Patient C', '11:55:00','14:00:00'),
        ('01-02-2019', 'OR 1', 'Patient D', '08:59:00','09:14:00'),
        ('01-02-2019', 'OR 1', 'Patient E', '11:02:00','13:30:00'),
        ('01-02-2019', 'OR 2', 'Patient F', '14:02:00','16:02:00'),
        ('01-03-2019', 'OR 2', 'Patient B', '07:55:00','11:00:00'),
        ('01-03-2019', 'OR 2', 'Patient C', '11:55:00','13:00:00'),
        ('01-03-2019', 'OR 3', 'Patient D', '08:59:00','09:14:00'),
        ('01-03-2019', 'OR 2', 'Patient E', '13:02:00','13:30:00'),
        ('01-03-2019', 'OR 3', 'Patient F', '14:02:00','16:02:00')
        ;

        --This code performs the object of the query 

        SELECT 
        T1.PatientName,
        T2.PatientName,
        T1.[OutTime]
       ,T2.InTime,
        T1.Room,
        T2.Room,
        datediff(mi,T1.OutTime,T2.InTime) AS Value
        FROM #operatingroom T1
        JOIN #operatingroom T2
        ON T2.[OutTime] > T1.[InTime]
        and T1.[Date] = T2.[Date] 
        and T1.Room = T2.Room 
        and T1.PatientName <> T2.PatientName
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9130/sql-server-window-functions-gaps-and-islands-problem/

Comment: Add a line to your query: `and T1.[OutTime] = (SELECT MAX(OutTime) from #operatingroom T3 WHERE OutTime < T2.[InTime] and T1.[Date] = T2.[Date] and T1.Room = T2.Room )`

Comment: And what if a patient is in OR1 from 1/1/2019 23:00:00 to 1/2/2019 01:00:00. As it is, that would be 2 rows to cover 2 different dates. Also, what if Patient 1 leaves OR1 at 1/1 11:59 and Patient 2 enters at 1/2 00:15? That's a 16 minute gap but across 2 different days.

Comment: SQL Server 2012.  L. Scott's solution worked quite well.  Good catch on the overnight scenario, Shawn.  I didn't think of that.  The only way I can think of solving that is to include the date in the InTime and OutTime.  Let me know if you can think of a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rank your Room / Date so that you can get the detail from the next record. Something like this:

```
 WITH Myrooms as (
      Select  Date, 
              Room, 
              PatientName, 
              InTime,
              OutTime, 
              DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Room, Date ORDER BY InTime) as PatientRank 
      From #OperatingRoom )

  Select Date, 
         Room, 
         PatientName, 
         M.InTime, 
         OutTime,
         CASE WHEN DateDiff(mi,M.OutTime, aa.InTime) >90 then NULL 
         else DateDiff(mi,M.OutTime, aa.InTime) END as Value 
  from Myrooms M
  OUTER APPLY
  (Select InTime from MyRooms MM 
   WHERE MM.Room=M.Room and MM.Date=M.Date and MM.PatientRank=M.PatientRank+1) aa
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I went one step further and gave you a way to find the average time between room usages, with the ability to set an interval to ignore.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c183a/20)

**Query**:

```
DECLARE @OnlyCountMinutes int 
SET @OnlyCountMinutes = 90  
DECLARE @OnlyCountSeconds int  
SET @OnlyCountSeconds = @OnlyCountMinutes*60 


SELECT s1.Room
    , AVG(secSinceLast) / 60.0 AS minutesSinceLast
FROM
(
  SELECT
       Room
     , InTime
     , OutTime
     , LEAD(InTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Room ORDER BY InTime) AS nextIn
     , LAG(OutTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Room ORDER BY OutTime) AS prevOut
     , DATEDIFF(second, LAG(OutTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Room ORDER BY OutTime), InTime) AS secSinceLast
     -- , DATEDIFF(second, outTime, LEAD(InTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Room ORDER BY InTime)) AS secUntilNext
  FROM OperatingRoom
) s1
WHERE ISNULL(s1.secSinceLast,@OnlyCountSeconds+1) < @OnlyCountSeconds
    -- AND ISNULL(s1.secUntilNext,@OnlyCountSeconds+1) < @OnlyCountSeconds
GROUP BY s1.Room
ORDER BY s1.Room
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c183a/20/0)**:

```
| Room | minutesSinceLast |
|------|------------------|
| OR 1 |             32.5 |
| OR 2 |             28.5 |
```

Like my suggestion above, I've combined the date and the times into one field. This will allow us to cross over days. Then I'm declaring a variable for you to set the number of minutes you want to set as the minimum amount of free time to ignore. I convert that to seconds. That's not really needed, especially if you don't track seconds or don't care how many seconds are between intervals. I switched to using the `LAG()` window function (which was also added in SQL2012), because you really more care about what happened before an entry that what happened after. Then I just use standard aggregation to compute the average interval per room, excluding your previous set limit.

**--------------------ORIGINAL--------------------**

Good news is, with SQL 2012, you can use the `LEAD()` Window Function.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c183a/20)

**Query Using Setup Info Above**:

```
SELECT Room
    , PatientName
    , Date
    , InTime
    , OutTime
    , nextIn
    , gapDiffInSeconds = DATEDIFF(second,OutTime,nextIn)
FROM
(
  SELECT
       PatientName
     , Room
     , [Date]
     , InTime
     , OutTime
     , nextIn     = LEAD(InTime) OVER (PARTITION BY [Room],[Date] ORDER BY [Date],[OutTime])
  FROM OperatingRoom
) s1
WHERE DATEDIFF(second,OutTime,nextIn) > 1
    -- AND DATEDIFF(second,OutTime,nextIn) < 5400 /* 60 seconds * 90 minutes = 5400 seconds */
ORDER BY Room, Date, InTime, OutTime
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c183a/20/0)**:

```
| Room | PatientName |       Date |           InTime |          OutTime |           nextIn | gapDiffInSeconds |
|------|-------------|------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| OR 1 |   Patient A | 2019-01-01 | 08:02:00.0000000 | 09:45:00.0000000 | 09:55:00.0000000 |              600 |
| OR 1 |   Patient B | 2019-01-01 | 09:55:00.0000000 | 11:00:00.0000000 | 11:55:00.0000000 |             3300 |
| OR 1 |   Patient D | 2019-01-02 | 08:59:00.0000000 | 09:14:00.0000000 | 11:02:00.0000000 |             6480 |
| OR 2 |   Patient B | 2019-01-03 | 07:55:00.0000000 | 11:00:00.0000000 | 11:55:00.0000000 |             3300 |
| OR 2 |   Patient C | 2019-01-03 | 11:55:00.0000000 | 13:00:00.0000000 | 13:02:00.0000000 |              120 |
| OR 3 |   Patient D | 2019-01-03 | 08:59:00.0000000 | 09:14:00.0000000 | 14:02:00.0000000 |            17280 |
```

If you want to filter out OR visits longer than a specific time, uncomment the `AND DATEDIFF(...)...` in the above query and use appropriate number of `SECONDS` that you want the difference to be.